# Adding withCount to collection json

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

So i've got two models, Client and Project, and Client has a hasMany relationship with projects. I'm just trying to add the project count for the client into the JSON response but I can't get it to work.

My controller just returns all the projects;

```
public function index(Client $client)
{
    return $client->all();
}
```

And my model contains the below;

```
protected $appends  = ['client_projects_count'];


/**
 * Create a relationship between this client and it's projects
 */
public function clientProjects() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}

public function getClientProjectsCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->withCount('clientProjects');
}
```

This just adds `client_projects_count` to the response but it's an empty array. I'm close, if I `dd($this->withCount('clientProjects')->get())` I can see the client_projects_count with the correct count, but if I remove the `dd` and keep the `->get()` then I get an internal server error.

Also, it is possible to only load this for the `index()` method rather than every one?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$clients = Client::withCount('projects')->get();

foreach ($clients as $client) {
    echo $client->projects_count;
}
```

Comment: So either of the last two lines go in the `getClientProjectsCountAttribute`? Where is `$client` coming from? I tried changing it to `$this` and get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::all()` for the $client->with,  and `return $client->withCount('projects')->get();` with the last line

Comment: @KeironLowe you need projectCount for one client or for a list of clients?

Comment: List of clients, I'm listing all the clients and want to add the amount of projects that client has

Comment: I've seen that but I'm not sure how that fits in to my situation? How can I apply that so that the count is added to the JSON when listing all the clients through the `index()` method in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to resolve it myself, although I'm sure their must be a nicer way.

**Client.php**

```
protected $appends  = ['client_projects_count'];


/**
 * Create a relationship between this client and it's projects
 */
public function clientProjects() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}

public function clientProjectsCount()
{
    return $this->clientProjects()->selectRaw('client_id, count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('client_id')->get();
}

public function getClientProjectsCountAttribute()
{
    return isset($this->clientProjectsCount()[0]) ? $this->clientProjectsCount()[0]->aggregate : 0;
}
```